# How can I create missing date records for each employee based off a limited calendar?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have two tables, one an abbreviated calendar:

```
create table dbo.calendar
(
    [date] datetime
)

insert into dbo.calendar values ('20150101 00:00:00 AM') -- 1/1/15
insert into dbo.calendar values ('20150102 00:00:00 AM') -- 1/2/15
insert into dbo.calendar values ('20150103 00:00:00 AM') -- 1/3/15
insert into dbo.calendar values ('20150104 00:00:00 AM') -- 1/4/15
```

and the other a time clock

```
create table dbo.timeclock
(
    id integer,
    punchtime datetime,
    punchtype varchar(25)
)

--employee 1
insert into dbo.timeclock values (1,'20150102 08:00:00 AM','in') -- 8am  1/2/15
insert into dbo.timeclock values (1,'20150102 05:00:00 PM','out') -- 5pm  1/2/15
insert into dbo.timeclock values (1,'20150103 08:00:00 AM','in') -- 8am  1/3/15
insert into dbo.timeclock values (1,'20150103 05:00:00 PM','out') -- 5pm  1/3/15

--employee 2
insert into dbo.timeclock values (2,'20150103 08:00:00 AM','in') -- 8am  1/3/15
insert into dbo.timeclock values (2,'20150103 05:00:00 PM','out') -- 5pm  1/3/15
```

What I'm wanting is to create in dbo.timeclock a 'no time entered' record for each day that each employee has no records for each date in the calendar. The end table would look like this:

```
id      punchtime               type
--------------------------------------------
1       20150101 00:00:00 AM    no time entered
1       20150102 08:00:00 AM    in
1       20150102 05:00:00 PM    out
1       20150103 08:00:00 AM    in
1       20150103 05:00:00 PM    out
1       20150104 00:00:00 AM    no time entered
2       20150101 00:00:00 AM    no time entered
2       20150102 00:00:00 AM    no time entered
2       20150103 08:00:00 AM    in
2       20150103 05:00:00 PM    out
2       20150104 00:00:00 AM    no time entered
```

I was able to do this using cursors, but it runs far too slow and I know it's not the 'correct' way of doing it.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a table that contains all the possible dates in the range, @alldates
2. Then insert your missing records with something like this:

Query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.timeclock
SELECT id
    ,d.punchtime
    ,'no time entered'
FROM (
    SELECT DATE
        ,id
    FROM @alldates d
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM dbo.timeclock
        ) ids
    ) userDateCross
LEFT JOIN dbo.timeclock ON timeclock.id = userdatecross.id
    AND userdatecross.DATE = timeclock.DATE
WHERE timeclock.punctype IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I was about to figure out what I needed from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a trigger that auto-populates your `dbo.timeclock` table when you insert into `dbo.calendar` with the default value `no time entered`. Then when you update your `dbo.timeclock` table use another trigger to remove this value after the addition of new values to the table.

This will automatically handle what you are describing as you input new values to your tables without having to think about it again.

Trigger for insert into `dbo.calendar`

```
CREATE TRIGGER timecard
AFTER INSERT ON dbo.calendar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.timecard 
        SELECT emp.id, NEW.date, "no time entered" 
            FROM dbo.employee AS emp
END;
```

Trigger for insert into `dbo.timecard`

```
CREATE TRIGGER newTime
AFTER INSERT ON dbo.timecard
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM dbo.timecard 
        WHERE punchtime=NEW.punchtime 
            AND id=NEW.id 
            AND punchtype="no time entered"
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive CTE to get the dates in the range. Another to create a calculated column with just the date from the punchtime field. Then left join them like so:

```
--Using a table variable just for the sample code.
declare @TimeClock as table (
    id integer,
    PunchTime datetime,
    PunchType varchar(25)
)

--employee 1
insert into @TimeClock values (1,'20150102 08:00:00 AM','in') -- 8am  1/2/15
insert into @TimeClock values (1,'20150102 05:00:00 PM','out') -- 5pm  1/2/15
insert into @TimeClock values (1,'20150103 08:00:00 AM','in') -- 8am  1/3/15
insert into @TimeClock values (1,'20150103 05:00:00 PM','out') -- 5pm  1/3/15

--employee 2
insert into @TimeClock values (2,'20150103 08:00:00 AM','in') -- 8am  1/3/15
insert into @TimeClock values (2,'20150103 05:00:00 PM','out') -- 5pm  1/3/15

declare
    @StartDate datetime = 'January 1, 2015',
    @EndDate datetime = 'January 30, 2015'

;with Dates as (
    select @StartDate CalendarDate
    union all
    select dateadd(d,1,CalendarDate) from Dates where dateadd(d,1,CalendarDate) <= @EndDate
),
TimeClockExpanded as (
    select
        id,
        PunchTime,
        dateadd(d,datediff(d,0,PunchTime),0) PunchDate,
        PunchType
    from
        @TimeClock
)
select
    id,
    coalesce(PunchTime,CalendarDate) PunchTime,
    PunchType
from
    Dates d
    left join TimeClockExpanded t on t.PunchDate = d.CalendarDate
order by
    PunchTime
```